# How to maintain an image cache in Pressflow with a load balancer?

Tags: drupal, load-balancing, image-caching, pressflow

I am planning to make a load-balancer for my website. It is [Pressflow](http://fourkitchens.com/pressflow-makes-drupal-scale) 6.20. How can I maintain an image cache in the two servers?

I need something other than [NFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System_%28protocol%29), since NFS will cause overload and will break the website in case that the server, that has the images, is down!

**EDIT**
Is it possible to have a dedicated server for images using an image cache (if so, how?)

Answer (score 0):

You should have your file system in a single location. In other words, just as the two servers use the same database - both servers will also use the same file system.

One option would be to mount the (remote) file system locally.

Comment: I know that i can use NFS,,, but i dont like to do so as i mentioned already in my question